# C# Fast Element Find Matrix as Matlab

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, matrix, emgucv

I have a 1000x1000 matrix and I use Emgu CV. **I try to find element index** in this matrix.

So first I try this in Matlab

```
test_matrix=rand(1000,1000);
tic
[row,col]=find(test_matrix==test_matrix(1,1));
toc;
```

> It is completed in 9.7 ms.

Then I use classic for loop in C#.

```
for (int i = 0; i < element_matrix.Height; i++)
 for (int j = 0; j < element_matrix.Width; j++)
    if (element_matrix[i, j] == finding_element)
       {
         Find_Row_List.Add(i);
         Find_Col_List.Add(j);         
       }
```

> It is completed in 460 ms.

Then I divide matrix to 10 small matrix and calculate every part in different threads.

```
             t1= new Thread(() => {
                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<element_matrix.Width;j++)
                    {
                        if(element_matrix[i,j]==finding_element)
                        {
                            Find_Row_List.Add(i);
                            Find_Col_List.Add(j);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            ...
            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
            ...
            t10.Start();

            t1.Join();
            t2.Join();
            ...
            t10.Join();
```

> It is completed in 310 ms.

I repeat this process for **20 small matrix and threads**.

> It is completed in 380 ms.

Then I use  Parallel.For

```
  Parallel.For(0, element_matrix.Height, i =>
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < element_matrix.Width; j++)
        {
            if(element_matrix[i,j]==finding_element)
            {
                Find_Row_List.Add(i);
                Find_Col_List.Add(j);
            }
        }
    });
```

> It is completed in 224 ms.

I use two threads and Parallel.For

```
      t1 = new Thread(() => {
            Parallel.For(0, 500, i =>
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < element_matrix.Width; j++)
                {
                    if (element_matrix[i, j] == finding_element)
                    {
                        Find_Row_List.Add(i);
                        Find_Col_List.Add(j);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        t2 = new Thread(() => {
            Parallel.For(500, 1000, i =>
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < element_matrix.Width; j++)
                {
                    if (element_matrix[i, j] == finding_element)
                    {
                        Find_Row_List.Add(i);
                        Find_Col_List.Add(j);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        t1.Join();
        t2.Join();
```

> It is completed in 240 ms.

**Summary**

```
**Method                       Duration (ms)**
------------------------       ------------
Matlab                         9.7
For Loop (Classic)             460
For Loop (10 threads)          310
For Loop (20 threads)          380
Parallel.For                   224
Parallel.For(2 threads)        250
```

**All durations are average of 10 calculation.**

I try different methods to calculation as fast as Matlab. The fastest solution is Parallel.For (224 ms). But it is 25 times slower than Matlab. How can i get improve this durations?

Comment: Are you looking for 1 element? If so, return after you find it so you don't have to iterate over the rest of collection if you already have the element.

Comment: What is `element_matrix` type in case of C#, please?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko element_matrix is  Matrix<double>(1000,1000) in Emgu.CV.Matrix

Comment: Do you want all the elements found or just 1

Comment: @FCin No. It is just an example. The number of elements I look for may vary.

Comment: @Saruman I want to find all element index in matrix.

Comment: The fastest way to do this, will be to write a C++ dll and use pointers and use threads. Second fastest will be to preallocate an array of struct as a result and use unsafe pointers count and threads. also calling anything like `element_matrix.width` constantly (or anything with a . in it)is going to slow it down as well.

Comment: Also this is better on codereview

Comment: When I test the *worst case* (the entire array scanned, no value found) for `double[,] matrix = new double[1000, 1000];` I got **~5 ms** (Core i7, 3.6Ghz) even for the simplest `foreach(var item in matrix)` implementation.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes. 2D array faster than Emgu.CV.Matrix. But in this scenario I convert to Emgu.Cv.Matrix to 2D Array and I have to find a method for this conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Your parallel stuff isn't thread safe.

Also the fastest way to do this is with unmanaged code, pointers, and (possibly) threads.

However this should be faster than what you have:

```
var width = Input.GetLength(0);
var height = Input.GetLength(1);
var array = new Point[width * height];
var count = 0;

fixed (Point* r = array)
fixed (double* pInput = Input)
{
   var len = array.Length;

   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
      if (*(pInput + i) == someValue)
      {
         var temp = r + count++;
         (*(temp)).X = i;
         (*(temp)).Y = i / width;
      }

   var result = new Point[count];
   Array.Copy(array, 0, result, 0, count);
   return result;
}
```

#Benchmarks

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mode             : Release (64Bit)
Test Framework   : .NET Framework 4.7.1 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operating System : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version          : 10.0.17134
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPU Name         : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Description      : Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7
Cores (Threads)  : 4 (8)      : Architecture  : x64
Clock Speed      : 3401 MHz   : Bus Speed     : 100 MHz
L2Cache          : 1 MB       : L3Cache       : 8 MB
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Results**

```
--- Standard input ---------------------------------------------------------
| Value   |    Average |    Fastest |    Cycles | Garbage | Test |    Gain |
--- Scale 100 ----------------------------------------------- Time 0.163 ---
| Unsafe2 |  23.472 µs |  21.013 µs |  81.444 K | 0.000 B | N/A  | 80.92 % |
| Index   | 123.034 µs | 114.073 µs | 420.831 K | 0.000 B | Base |  0.00 % |
--- Scale 1,000 -------------------------------------------- Time 16.477 ---
| Unsafe2 |   2.940 ms |   2.324 ms |   9.761 M | 0.000 B | N/A  | 76.77 % |
| Index   |  12.657 ms |  12.021 ms |  43.033 M | 0.000 B | Base |  0.00 % |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You could make this parallel, though I'm not sure you will get all that much performance gain with TPL; you will get some, however it will be a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look into "Math.Net" Library for the multi-dimension operation.

```
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var test_matrix = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(1000, 1000, 0);

        double finding_Element = 1;
        test_matrix[999, 999] = finding_Element;
        test_matrix[998, 999] = finding_Element;

        var result = new List<ValueTuple<int, int>>();

        for (int row = 0; row < 1000; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < 1000; column++)
            {
                if (test_matrix[row, column] == finding_Element)
                {
                    result.Add(new ValueTuple<int, int>(row, column));
                }
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Find List of Result: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

        var sw1 = new Stopwatch();
        sw1.Start();
        var result2 = test_matrix.Find(x => x.Equals(finding_Element)); // First Value
        sw1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Find First Occurence: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

My result here is about 34ms to get the list of occurrence or first occurrence

Comment: Thank you for your interest. My other option is Math.Net Library. I'll try this.